# MySQL Workbench - alter database query (Local Connection Database)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to run an alter database query on  the Schema I am designing in the Workbench software.
is this at all possible?
I want to run this in the Workbench Scripting Shell on the Schema called "BACKDOOR" within the Table called "SATURDAY"

```
"alter table SATURDAY add column flavor"
```

It does not work for me though :

```
File "<string>", line 1
alter table SATURDAY add column flavor
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error executing script.
```

I do not have MySQL Installed on this pc. Im am going on the basis that the code snippets in the Workbench Scripter work fine eg

```
schema = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0]
for table in schema.tables:
    print table.name
```

This gives me all the table names from the database I'm designing in the Workbench software.
I guess I need to wrap my SQL statement in a similar fashion to the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "alter table SATURDAY add column flavor"

The proper syntax for adding a column on a table is slightly different in MySQL ([MySQL ALTER TABLE examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table-examples.html)):

```
alter table SATURDAY add flavor varchar;
```